# Android - Focusable EditTexts and Layout Behaviour

Tags: android

Sorry for the vague title. I am having some strange behaviour creating a simple log-in page. I have two Edit-Texts in my layout (Username, Password). I am saving their state between orientation changes using some global booleans and the saved/restoe instance state methods along with EditText.RequestFocus();.

My issue is, this all works perfeclty fine if I have this flag in my passords EditText layout:

android:scrollbars="vertical"

When the view loads, the username is set to focused (automatically by Android it seems) and my code to retain the focus works perfectly. As well as this when the soft keyboard appears, it neatly resizes my layout to incorperate the change.

However, after removing that flag, this all breaks. No EditText is set to focused when the activity loads. My code to retain focusable on orientation change does not work and most annoyingly, the keyboard blocks some of the layout instead of resizing it.

I don't want to keep this useless flag in my layout, as I am worried this behaviour might change between version and the app might not work for other devices. Any help or suggestions?

Thanks,

Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this isn't a total answer to my question, I thought I would quickly post how I got around this real quick:

Placing this in my manifest (for the activity i wanted):             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

This seemed to do pretty much the same thing as what the scrollbars were doing - I still have no explanation of that odd behaviour so if anybody has a clue I'd be interested to know. However I believe this is the *correct* way of handling this situation anyway.

I am clueless as to why my code to save state would work one way but not the other.